# Ninject Bindings with MVC5 sessions and Web API 2 sessionless in the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I've a ASP.NET MVC5 Web project where I use default MVC controller where I use InSessionScope bindings (works fine so far). I am using the

```
Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost
```

extension, which creates the "NinjectWebCommon.cs" file in my "App_Data" folder.

Now I've added a Web API 2 controller to my project and the

```
Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost
```

extension.

But when I Call a Web API function, with my MVC5 bindings I get a error when I try to bind it to SessionScope.

so my question is, how can I create a seperate "NinjectWebCommon.cs" file or separate bindings for my Web API 2 calls in the same project? Or how can I tell Ninject to bind my InSessionScope Bindings in RequestScope, when it calls my WebApi Controller / authentication, ...

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Nullreference, because the Web API can't access the Session. But I can't find a solution how to tell ninject to use implementation X when injected into a default mvc Controller and use implementation Y when Injected into a ApiController